# stress out: the meaning of 'out'

Tags: phrase-meaning

> I was really stressed **out** before finals.

> I'd been working flat out and was stressed **out**.

> I've got too much to do and I'm completely stressed **out**.

I wonder why we need '**out**' here. What's the meaning of 'out'?

Comment: It's an idiom, and the exact history might be unknowable. Be alert to answers that sound good but provide no documentation.

Comment: It's one of language's 'emphasis fillers'. English uses a lot of 'directions' which aren't actually indicative of movement. Stressed out, screwed up, pissed off, etc.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney unknowable to anyone without a dictionary.

Comment: @Atralbee, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3):

Cambridge defines this particular use of 'out' as:

> **out** adverb, preposition (VERY)
> used to make the meaning of a word stronger.

The cited example is to "sort [something] out", meaning to deal with it completely.

Other common uses include '[chill out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chill-out)', to relax completely; 'tired out', meaning completely exhausted; and your example, 'stress out', to become excessively stressed over something.